# How to close the current form and open another at the same time

Tags: c#, winforms

I have to forms in my project one form to connect and the main form I want when the user and the password are true to close the current login form and open the main form, I created the code which check if the user name and the password are true, and I used an IF statement if the check is true, but the problem is when I press the connect button the two forms are disappeared this is the code I tried to use :

```
if (allowCnx)
{
    Form1 mainForm = new Form1();
    mainForm.Show();
    this.Close();
 }
```

Comment: Is your form to connect the one opened by Application.Run()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The likely problem here is that you likely have your login form set as the main form (or the form that is run on startup).  When that form is closed the entire application closes.

There are a number of solutions, but one that I would suggest is to ensure that `Form1` is set as the actual startup form, and then in it's form load method have something like this:

```
Hide();
LoginForm otherForm = new LoginForm();
otherForm.ShowDialog();
if(otherForm.Success)
{
    Show();
}
else
{
    Close();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new frmSplashScreen());
        Application.Run(new frmMain());
    }
}

    private void tmr_Tick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        if (progBr.Value < progBr.Maximum)
        {
            progBr.Value += 10;
        }
        else
        {
            tmr.Enabled = false;

            this.Close();

        }
    }
```